# How to tunnel traffic from one machine to another?

Tags: 11.04, 10.10, networking, port-forwarding

I have a server, which can be seen from outside of my small network, sever has domain name and such. And I have a local machine, which can be seen by server, but is not accessible from outside.

So I want to be able to connect to port on the sever, but talk to my local machine instead.

Can I make traffic arriving on one port on the server be relayed to another port on my local machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use openssh to do so:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding

The commands to look for are -L or -R.

Let's say you want to forward port 4444 on the server to port 5555 on the local machine. On the Server use

```
ssh -L 4444:local_machine_name:5555 user@local_machine_name
```

or on the local machine use

```
ssh -R 4444:localhost:5555 user@server_machine_name
```

(In the first example you could connect to any other machine, no need to connect to local_machine_name, you could just use localhost to connect to the server itself).

Another more complex way is to use the server as a router. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router and especially https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router#Enable_IP_forwarding_and_Masquerading.
This is what most small cable or DSL home router do.

Comment: Method with ssh works, but only for duration of the session, and requires password of user of local machine. I wanted something what could be started up automatically on the server. But still, thanks!

Comment: Guess you could use keep-alive packet for the ssh session and a non password login. Never tried it but check out following:

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152
http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/02/03/keeping-ssh-sessions-alive/

Answer (score 3):

This is possible using iptables. There is a nice howto on [linuxhomenetworking.com](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch14_%3a_Linux_Firewalls_Using_iptables#Port_Forwarding_Type_NAT_.28DHCP_DSL.29) and more info on iptables can be found on the [ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) .
Note that there is also a GUI interface to iptables called [Firestarter](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firestarter).